# ServiceStack Swagger DTO won't Exclude

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I'm having a problem with excluding a specific DTO from Swagger in my ServiceStack application.  Here's my setup:

```
[Route("/lists", "GET")]
public class GetLists : IReturn<GetListsResponse>
{
}

[Route("/lists", "POST")]
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]
public class CreateList : IReturn<CreateListResponse>
{
}
```

The behavior I'm expecting is the Swagger will remove the POST request docs but not the GET.  Instead I'm getting both of them listed.  Any help with what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**  I have tried adding the following attribute to no success:

```
[Restrict(VisibilityTo = RequestAttributes.None)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visibility of different Request DTO's should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1585e4a74f23f7f938d6297d44e6ca2d97f78987) that's available from v4.0.55 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API), it looks like you can either exclude *properties* of a DTO or all services using a DTO -- but it doesn't say anything about excluding only certain verbs.

Comment: I can confirm that this is probably correct.  Except I was under the impression that the DTO was just the class object and I didn't think it would care about the route.  That way I was hoping to exclude the CreateLists DTO but not the GetLists (cause they're separate classes).  I'm still not sure, When excluding the WSDL etc it works fine, It's just Swagger that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict Visibility using the [Restrict] attribute. (see [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services)). This is a class based attribute and should be placed on your Service class. Visibility affects whether or not the service shows up on the public /metadata pages (& I am hoping for Swagger as well).

Have you tried the below?

```
[Route("/lists", "POST")]
[Restrict(VisibilityTo = RequestAttributes.None)]
public class CreateList : IReturn<CreateListResponse>
{
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work,  it is still visible in the documentation.  I have updated my question.